# Sqlalchemy - Filtering parent and chidren objects at the same time

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got this many-to-many design

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_number = Column(String)
    start_date = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    end_date = Column(DateTime)
    children= relationship("Child", lazy="selectin")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_date = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    end_date = Column(DateTime)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id"))
```

Both models have a `start_date` and `end_date` to register the validity date range of each row resulting in a compound primary key.

What I want to do is being able to construct the `Parent` object that satisfies a criteria on the `start_date`and `end_date` along with the children array.

I've tried a simple query like

```
session.query(Parent)
.filter(Parent.parent_number == '1234')
.filter(Parent.start_date > given_date & Parent.end_date < given_date)
```

which results in two queries

```
SELECT *
FROM Parent
WHERE parent_number = '1234' AND start_date > '2024-02-14' AND end_date < '2024-02-14'
 
SELECT Parent.id, Parent.start_date, Child.*
FROM Parent
JOIN Child ON Child.parent_id = Parent.id
WHERE (Parent.id, Parent.start_date) IN ((id_of_previous_parent, start_date_of_previous_parent))
```

The first query is fine, but for the second one, I'd like something like

```
SELECT Parent.id, Parent.start_date, Child.*
FROM Parent
JOIN Child ON Child.parent_id = Parent.id
WHERE (Parent.id, Parent.start_date) IN ((id_of_previous_parent, start_date_of_previous_parent)) AND Child.start_date > '2024-02-14' AND Child.end_date < '2024-02-14'
```

I've tried the naive query

```
session.query(Parent)
.filter(Parent.parent_number == '1234')
.filter(Parent.start_date > given_date & Parent.end_date < given_date)
.filter(Child.start_date > given_date & Child.end_date < given_date)
```

but it only changed the first query.

I also tried to join in the query like

```
session.query(Parent)
.join(Child)
.filter(Parent.parent_number == '1234')
.filter(Parent.start_date > given_date & Parent.end_date < given_date)
.filter(Child.start_date > given_date & Child.end_date < given_date)
```

with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the returned related objects using [criteria in loader options](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#adding-criteria-to-loader-options).

In this case, a criterion like this would include only children within the start date to end date range.

```py
orm.selectinload(
    Parent.children.and_(
         Child.start_date == start_date, Child.end_date <= end_date
    )
)
```

The full query would look like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

query = (
    session.query(Parent)
    .filter(sa.and_(Parent.start_date >= start_date, Parent.end_date <= end_date))
    .options(
        orm.selectinload(
            Parent.children.and_(
                Child.start_date == start_date, Child.end_date <= end_date
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The syntax is the same using 2.0-style code:

```py
q = (
    sa.select(Parent)
    .where(sa.and_(Parent.start_date >= start_date, Parent.end_date <= end_date))
    .options(
        orm.selectinload(
            Parent.children.and_(
                Child.start_date == start_date, Child.end_date <= end_date
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Will this add criteria to the `JOIN ON` condition or to the `WHERE`? I mean, will results contain Parents without child elements if Parent's date is Ok, but Children's dates are not Ok

Comment: I've just tested it and the criteria is added to the `JOIN` condition

Comment: @GuillaumeA, I asked it because in your desirable SQL query (from your question) these conditions are in the `WHERE` statement. But I guess it was just a mistake.

Comment: @YuriiMotov Oh you're right, I've just realized that. It was not an error on my side, I need to filter the data also so it should be in the `WHERE` clause... Do you know a solution ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb what if the children class also has a childchild relationship on which I want to apply the same filtering on the start and end dates ?

Comment: @GuillaumeA Not tested it, but I should imagine the same technique could be applied, except the criterion would be `Child.children.and_(...)`

Comment: @snakecharmerb nope it doesn't, I got an exception as it expects a root model, something like `Parent.children.grandchildren` but this does not work either

Comment: ahahah right, but I think I've found the solution: `selectinload(Parent.children).selectinload(Child.grandchildren).and_(.....)` does the trick